# MYSQL remove duplicates from table with two columns

Tags: mysql

Have table **contents_tags**

```
+------------+--------+
| content_id | tag_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      1 |
|          1 |      2 |
|          1 |      2 |
|          2 |      3 |
|          2 |      4 |
|          2 |      4 |
```

I want create unique index with two columns

```
alter table contents_tags ADD UNIQUE `contents_tags` (`content_id`, `tag_id`);
```

But I already have duplicate entries and get error:

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'contents_tags'

```
alter IGNORE table contents_tags ADD UNIQUE `contents_tags` (`content_id`, `tag_id`);
```

**IGNORE** - don't work in Mysql 8

How can I remove duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete all but unique values first. One of the options is using of *intermediate* table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp 
AS SELECT DISTINCT content_id, tag_id FROM contents_tags;

TRUNCATE contents_tags;

INSERT INTO contents_tags SELECT * FROM tmp;

DROP TABLE tmp;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6T6PXHvGF8V9HbFfiompk/0

Comment: Note: For creating a temporary table, you should have used `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: I would replace "should" to "can" ;)  "Real" temporary tables have *limitations by size*, aren't they? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Good point, and also creating a temporary table might use up a lot of server memory, which isn't always a good thing.  Maybe call it an "intermediate" table or something like that :-)

Comment: It's better to define `tmp` as TEMPORARY - it'd be deleted automatically during connection close (explicit DROP not needed). And, if final table data is not huge, then it's useful to define this table as `ENGINE=Memory` for disk writing minimize.

Comment: @Akina I'd leave the answer as is, but I hope Alex will count comments are useful. About temporary table limitations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: I do not see any problems which may occur according to this limitations in this process. I doubt that OP have NDB cluster. The only problem seen is that such static/temporary table may already exist - that is why explicit TEMPORARY is preferred, and some long name of random chars is more safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
DELETE FROM contents_tags 
WHERE 
    content_id IN (
    SELECT 
        content_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            content_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY content_id,tag_id 
                ORDER BY content_id,tag_id) AS row_num
        FROM 
            contents_tags 

    ) t
    WHERE row_num > 1
);
```

Comment: All duplicated records wil be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to make a UNIQUE key on two columns that is the entire table it might as well be the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE contents_tags2 (
  `content_id` INTEGER,
  `tag_id` INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`,  `tag_id`)
  );

INSERT INTO  contents_tags2 SELECT DISTINCT content_id, tag_id FROM contents_tags;

RENAME TABLE contents_tags TO contents_tags_del, contents_tags2 TO contents_tags;

DROP TABLE contents_tags_del;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6T6PXHvGF8V9HbFfiompk/0)

Comment: Renaming will fail if some foreign keys exists (if FK to non-unique possible - don't remember). And anycase triggers will be lost if exists.

Answer (score 0):

One more way if you are okay to drop your table.

`IGNORE` support for `ALTER TABLE` has been deprecated from `5.6` version if i'm not wrong. But you can still use `IGNORE` in `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TABLE contents_tags_new LIKE contents_tags;

ALTER TABLE contents_tags_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX (content_id ,tag_id );

INSERT IGNORE INTO contents_tags_new SELECT * FROM contents_tags;

DROP TABLE contents_tags;

RENAME TABLE contents_tags_new TO contents_tags;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d39862fc51dad8752a8ccd9cdfd070c)